# how find regex pattern word in outre word in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have the string like this : 
`str = '4    167213860 Mar 7 2017 10:37:42 +00:00 c7600rsp72043-advipservicesk9-mz-obs_v151_3_s1_RLS10_ES5'`

I want to recover only one part of this word (c7600rsp72043-advipservicesk9-mz-obs_v151_3_s1_RLS10_ES5)

I looking for the regex pattern, but I can't find. I do something like that in python :

```
import re

str = '4    167213860 Mar 7 2017 10:37:42 +00:00 c7600rsp72043-advipservicesk9-mz-obs_v151_3_s1_RLS10_ES5'

output = re.findall(r'[a-z0-9]rsp[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$',string)
```

This return me `[]`

If some one of you can help me I will be very happy.

Comment: Don't you just want `str.split()[-1]`? Note that it's unwise to name your own variable str, though; you shadow the built-in.

Comment: The first step in every such problem: write, in English words, the rule that tells you *why* you want the specific part of the string that you do, and *how you know* that that's the part you want.

Comment: looks like a directory listing; why not just use `os.listdir()` or `glob` yourself?

Comment: No, I really need to use the regex pattern, but it's interessting what you wrote. Tkank you for your suggestions !

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex that gets all adjacent non whitespace at the end of the string: `\S+$`

```
string = '4    167213860 Mar 7 2017 10:37:42 +00:00 c7600rsp72043-advipservicesk9-mz-obs_v151_3_s1_RLS10_ES5'

output = re.findall(r'\S+$',string)
```

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/lXFRNT/1

Answer (score 0):

@Ruzhim's answer is good, but if you want to keep on doing it the way you thought about it you could just replace the "rsp" bit with a `\w+`

```
output = re.findall(r'[a-z0-9]\w+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$', str)

>>>['c7600rsp72043-advipservicesk9-mz-obs_v151_3_s1_RLS10_ES5']
```

Comment: Thank you some much for help !:)